# How to store a character string into a character pointer declared in a structure

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>



    struct p{

           char* d;
           };

    typedef struct p* pt;

    int main(){
        pt opt;
        opt=(pt)malloc(sizeof(struct p));

        scanf("%s",(opt->d));


        printf("%s",opt->d);



        getch();

        return 0;

        }
```

Everytime I run it , it accepts and prints the string fine but an error occur.
On debugging it tells that there is a segmentation fault but doesn't points to where it is?
What is going wrong , It's seems to be fairly correct.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: @CarlNorum More precisely, you **must not** cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the scanf put the scanned string to a char buffer. but in your code your char pointer is not pointing to any thing it should be pointed to a buffer

If your gcc> 2.7, you can use `"%ms"`. this will allow to scanf to allocate memory for your pointer

```
scanf("%ms",(opt->d));
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `malloc` to allocate space for your structure, but not for the string you want to read in.  You need to do that too.  Here's an example paraphrased from your question:

```
 pt opt = malloc(sizeof(struct p));
 opt->d = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yupp, the problem is that you have to allocate memory for `char * d;`

1) Allocated the memory for `char * d` like (Mentioned in above reply)
`opt->d = malloc(expected_max_len + 1);`

2) Or you can declare buffer with maximum buffer length in structure:
`char d[MAX_LENGTH];`

Comment: You should note that 1 and 2 have different effects and require different measures to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate memory for `char* d;`

```
int main(){
    pt opt;
    opt=(pt)malloc(sizeof(struct p));
    opt->d = malloc( sizeof( char )* 80);
    scanf("%s",(opt->d));    //this might overflow
```

Comment: Please, don't cast `void *` to `T *`.

Answer (score 0):

You need pass correct buffer to `scanf` not just point-to-somewhere pointer.

```
struct p{
   char* d;
};

typedef struct p* pt;

int main(){
    pt opt;
    opt=(pt)malloc(sizeof(struct p));

    opt->d = malloc(expected_max_len + 1);

    scanf("%s",(opt->d));


    printf("%s",opt->d);

    free(opt->d);


    getch();

    return 0;

}
```