# C : scanf skips the first iteration while taking char* inputs from user through scanf

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to get Subject names from user using dynamic memory allocation and char **. I am not sure its the best way to do so.

Problem : scanf is getting skipped for first iteration in for loop. Tried with putting " %s", "\n%s" as suggested from StackOverflow but still facing the same.

Here is my code :

```
int nSubjects;
char **subNames;

printf("\nEnter no. of Subjects : ");
scanf("%d",&nSubjects);

subNames = malloc(nSubjects *  sizeof(char*));

 for(i=0;i<nSubjects;i++){

    *(subNames+i)= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    printf("\nEnter Subject %d name : ",i+1);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",subNames[i]);
}
```

Complete code (if required): http://pastebin.com/7Ncw0mWF

Please guide me where I am doing wrong in this code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: don't use `fflush(stdin);` it causes undefined behavior on other then Microsoft compilers, Also don't cast returned address of malloc and calloc in C

Comment: Instead of using `*(subNames+i)`, why not the more easy to understand `subNames[i]`? You do it later?

Comment: To help avoid allocation size bugs, use GNU `getline()` (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) or something similar to read dynamically sized strings. If you're not using a GNU toolchain a public domain (if not particularly efficient) version can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12169132/12711

Comment: and `"%s"` ---> `" %s"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY tried it. Couldn't help :(

Comment: @Kartik: give an example of your input - does it contain whitespace within the lines of data?

Comment: For no. of subject I am giving 5. Then loop starts : 
Enter Subject 1 name :
Enter Subject 2 name : __(cmd pointer)

Comment: malloc , fflush, scanf ,To work correctly if you modify correctly. And utilizing a different code otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelBurr here is the complete code http://pastebin.com/7Ncw0mWF

Comment: i insert test print. it work fine. Do you or not enter a non-numeric in place of typing twice the number in the first place?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am entering number then press enter. Please have a look to complete code http://pastebin.com/7Ncw0mWF

Comment: There is a problem with your code(other place). In order to inspect the part in question is now about after the input of the subject `for (i = 0; i <nSubjects; ++i) {
printf ("%s\n", subNames [i]);}` 
Try to check by inserting this.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ohh can you tell me where ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocation is  wrong for string in side loop:

```
*(subNames+i)= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

should be:

```
*(subNames+i)=  malloc(sizeof(char) * (string_lenght + 1));
```

Additionally, don't use `fflush(stdin);` it causes undefined behavior on other then Microsoft compilers, Also [don't cast returned address of `malloc()` and `calloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Read: [Why `fflush(stdin)` is wrong?](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351),  and read: [`fflush` @msdn.microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for very quick response. I changed the allocation code as you said and removed fflush. But still facing the problem :(

Comment: Don't know whats the problem actually.. :(

Comment: @Kartik Try by replacing `scanf("%s",subNames[i]);` with `scanf(" %s",subNames[i]);`  added a space before `%` in format string in scanf ..

Comment: Tried with that as well. Couldnot help :(

Comment: @Kartik I checked you code you have many mistakes in format string in your code e.g. `scanf("%d",&p->name);`  should be `scanf("%s",p->name);`   Compile your code  with `gcc -Wall`  you will get to know.

Answer (score 0):

Your malloc is wrong:

```
 *(subNames[i]) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

You are trying to allocate memory for a char** which is actually then being converted to a char*. You also need the specify the size of length, or this will allocate a single pointer. Note: subNames[i] doesn't need to be dereferenced.

The below should work:

```
  (subNames[i]) =  (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (string_length + 1));
```

Note: you will have to declare the string length variable, maybe perhaps as 1000, and then realloc it to the strlen of the string entered afterwards.

Comment: Tried it. But still the same problem. Here is the complete code http://pastebin.com/7Ncw0mWF

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is gcc and your gcc> 2.7, you can use `"%ms"`. this will allow scanf to allocate memory for your pointer:

```
for(i=0;i<nSubjects;i++){
    printf("\nEnter Subject %d name : ",i+1);
    scanf("%ms",&subNames[i]);
}
```

[How to store a character string into a character pointer declared in a structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255937/how-to-store-a-character-string-into-a-character-pointer-declared-in-a-structure/16255964#16255964)

Comment: Whether the completely non-portable %ms hack works is not a feature of the compiler, but of the standard IO library, of which scanf is a part of. So it's likely a glibc thing, not a gcc thing.